# Custom DateTimePicker: getting a consistent look and feel

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, textbox, custom-controls

I'm creating a custom `ComboBox` that allows the user to select a date; the calendar display is localized making the built-in `DateTimePicker` undesirable [see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;889834&x=18&y=19) for more information]. I need the UI control to mirror the look and feel or the existing components. Here's what I've tried and the problems I've encountered:

- Using a `TextBox` with a drawn `ComboBox` button: I've tried using `ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton` but the look and feel does not mirror the existing UI controls. In particular we don't have `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` so the buttons have a Windows 98 look and feel. `ComboBoxRenderer` draws a glossy grey button.
- Using a `ComboBox` and a `ToolStripDropDown` to contain the calender control: the button has the correct look and feel but I cannot hide the drop down box completely. Even though the `ToolStripControlHost` is effectively hiding the drop down box, when I click the button, I can see the drop down box being rendered just before the `ToolStripDropDown` is displayed. I've tried workarounds that effectively disable the drop down box but the button, as you would expect, does not maintain the desired visual state of being pressed (and drawing the button brings me back to the problem in the above point).
  Setting the height of the drop down box to zero in `OnMeasureItem` does not work; though I suppose I could make the drop down box the same height as my calendar UI selector so that the rendering doesn't look particularly bad.

Are there existing mechanisms to get the behaviour I need: a `TextBox` that displays the selected date with a drop down arrow button that, when clicked, displays a calendar UI selection component. The calendar component already exists and the button must look like the existing Windows 98 look and feel `ComboBox` buttons.

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a clear solution so I've implemented a workaround: I've taken a screenshot of the Windows 98 style button in the *normal* and *pressed* state (there isn't a *hover* state) and added them as an image resource (in a *resx* file). I then draw the image according to the current user interaction. This has several consequences including: any changes to the visual style will not be seamless and if the control height is changed, the button won't resize like other `ComboBox` instances.